# Running Wave In A Box in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip, google-wave

I have gotten WIAB to properly run on my localmachine, but am a bit confused on the process for setting it up to work with AWS EC2. Currently the run-server.sh is running without any problems, however I don't believe I have it configured properly. Should wave_server_domain, http_frontend_public_address, http_frontend_addresses all be hooked up to my elastic IP, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need Elastic IP, you can use the public DNS instead.
To get some info on the settings setup - please read the server.config.example property file.
Basically it goes like this:
wave_server_domain - can by anything you like, usually the same as your domain (example.com)
http_frontend_public_address - this is the public address your WIAB server can be reached, for example: example.com:9898. You can use your public DNS or Elastic IP instead of the domain name "example.com"
http_frontend_addresses - the comma separated list of addresses the WIAB server ninds itself to. Usually your local IP address that you can get from "ifconfig", or from the properties of the instance as shown in the console.